# is it possible in layout xml file referring some id, but the value of that id points to could be changed?

Tags: android, android-layout

Or the question could be can the element in layout file referring to a 'variable' whose value could be changed at run time?

One similar case is we could specify the element height as the actionBar's height

android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

And get the actual height based on the device it is running.

The use case would be having a layout element, its height is changing dynamically. Is it possible in the layout file to point the height to a 'variable', and at run time just dynamically change the variable's value, so that when the layout is inflated it will pick up the most recent value?

Comment: Use values folder in resource to define different values for different device configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Create different values folder like this

```
res/values/dimens.xml    
res/values-small/dimens.xml    
res/values-normal/dimens.xml    
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

depending on the device values will be picked automatically from on of the folder

Define values inside `dimens.xml` like

```
<dimen name="my_val">50dp</dimen>
```

and use it in the code like this

```
int myVal = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_val);
```

Comment: put some variations for some dimensions are the thought, but the value cannot be predefined.

Comment: dont want to access the view's layout at runtime, instead just set that vale to the 'id' of the view element is referring, because this layout is used in many places in different parent containers. Maybe making a subclass for that specific layout and override its onMeasure() or some thing.

Comment: you don't have to assign values are run time. Just put them into the xml and android will take care of the rest. All you have to do is create different xml for different device configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean programmatically then you can use `view.setLayoutParams` to set the height and width. Otherwise you can always have a `dimens.xml` file in which you store the values folders for different configurations